# How do I update my list from a lookup list

Tags: c#, linq

How do I update `ValueToGet` property in `list` object by using `key` property and looking value up in the `listLookup` object?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/2evICp

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Arrange
        //Keys needed to get ValueToGet property
        var key1 = new WidgetA{Id = 1, Key = 50};
        var key2 = new WidgetA{Id = 1, Key = 100};
        var key3 = new WidgetA{Id = 1, Key = 150};
        List<WidgetA> list = new List<WidgetA>();
        list.Add(key1);
        list.Add(key2);
        list.Add(key3);
        //Lookups
        var keyLookup1 = new WidgetB()
        {Id = 1, KeyLookup = 50, ValueLookup = "Fifty"};
        var keyLookup2 = new WidgetB()
        {Id = 2, KeyLookup = 100, ValueLookup = "One hundred"};
        var keyLookup3 = new WidgetB()
        {Id = 3, KeyLookup = 150, ValueLookup = "One hundred and fifty"};
        List<WidgetB> listLookup = new List<WidgetB>();
        listLookup.Add(keyLookup1);
        listLookup.Add(keyLookup2);
        listLookup.Add(keyLookup3);
    //Act
    /* How do I populate ValueToGet property in list using key to match in listLookup? */
    }
}

public class WidgetA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Key { get; set; }

    public string ValueToGet { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int KeyLookup { get; set; }

    public string ValueLookup { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand you question. You want to iterate list of `WidgetA` and `WidgetB`, which are linked by a foreign key `WidgetA.Key == WidgetB.KeyLookup`? And if it matches you want to do (...something?)

Comment: Correct, I want to update ValueToGet in list with ValueLookup in listLookup

Comment: For each element in `list`, search the matched element in `listLookup`.

Answer (score 3):

Lists are not ideal for lookups. Use a dictionary instead.

```cs
var lookupDict = new Dictionary<int, WidgetB> {
    [keyLookup1.KeyLookup] = keyLookup1,
    [keyLookup2.KeyLookup] = keyLookup2,
    [keyLookup3.KeyLookup] = keyLookup3,
};
```

Of course, you can also add the items with

```cs
lookupDict.Add(keyLookup4.KeyLookup, keyLookup4);
```

or, if your data comes from an enumerable source

```cs
var lookupDict = listLookup.ToDictionary(x => x.KeyLookup);
```

Dictionaries have a quick lookup time of `O(1)` whereas lists have `O(n)` or with binary search on a sorted list `O(log(n))`. Now, you can look up and update like this:

```cs
foreach (WidgetA widgetA in list) {
    if (lookupDict.TryGetValue(widgetA.Key, out WidgetB lookup)) {
        widgetA.ValueToGet = lookup.ValueLookup;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I turned my code around, because it makes more sense to put the `WidgetB`s into a dictionary. The name `ValueToGet` is a bit confusing. It should probably be named `PropertyToSet` and in `WidgetB` `ValueToLookup`.